# Django - How to get current url from template and replace parameter value or delete parameter and append after

Tags: python, django, django-templates

In my django template I need to get the current url and modify a parameter value or add this parameter if not present.

here's an url example : **/articles/pdf?perpage=2&page=2**

All I know so far is how to retrieve the whole url :

```
{{ request.get_full_path }}
```

But what I need to do is to be able to create a new url that I will use as an href in which if "page" parameter present, I change its value, or if not present, I append this parameter to the url.

**EDIT : Is it that hard that no one knows how to do this ?....**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it seems to be a hard question... I had to find a workaround to achieve it.

I cut the "page" parameter in all its forms, and then append the new one inside the href :

```
{% define request.GET.page as page_num %}
{% define "?page="|add:page_num as page_first_param %}
{% define "&page="|add:page_num as page_next_param %}
{% define request.get_full_path|cut:page_first_param|cut:page_next_param as new_partial_url %}
{% if '?' in new_partial_url %} {% define "&" as p %} {% else %} {% define "?" as p %} {% endif %}
{% define new_partial_url|add:p as new_full_url %}
                
    <a class="page-link" href="{{ new_full_url }}page={{ items.previous_page_number}}">
    « Précédent</a>
```

Comment: beautiful! Almost makes me wounder why nobody came up with this one before!